# Why isn't my tableView loading?

Tags: iphone, ios, tableview, xcode4.2, storyboard

I have the following code, where I believe the `NSFetchRequest` is in fact working, but there is nothing showing in my tableView(peopleList) after the `viewWillAppear` runs.

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{

  AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
  NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [appDelegate managedObjectContext]; 

  NSEntityDescription *entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Person" 
                                                     inManagedObjectContext:moc];

  NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
  [request setEntity:entityDescription];


  NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"firstName" ascending:YES];
  [request setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]];


  NSError *error = nil;

  NSLog(@"Count for request is %a", [moc countForFetchRequest:request error:&error]);

  personArray = [moc executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

  [peopleList reloadData];
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

  static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";

  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
  if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
  }

  NSString *cellValue = [personArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
  cell.textLabel.text = cellValue;

  return cell;

}
```

Just in case, my storyboard is hooked up as shown.

[image]

My console says "Count for request is 23", making me think that the breakdown is somewhere in getting the array itself to show up in the interface.  What needs to happen to get my personArray to show up in peopleList?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare a UITableViewDataSource, which is an object that implements that protocol and supplies data to your table.  This is the piece that calls cellForRowAtIndexPath.  It is frequently self  -i.e. the tableViewController class, because it usually has the array as a local variable.

```
myTableView.dataSource = self;
```

And in your header file, do something like this:

```
 @interface myTableViewController : UITableViewController <UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource> {

 }
```

Comment: I get a 'Passing 'MainScreen *const_strong' to parameter of incompatible type 'id<UITableViewDataSource>' error.

Comment: Is your table view controller declaring that it implements the UITableViewDataSource protocol?  See my last edit.

Comment: No, it wasn't, but I have corrected that. Now it is throwing an exception, and claiming the line "cell.textLabel.text = cellValue;" is the problem. Console says 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Person isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x912f2c0'.

Comment: What kind of objects are in your personArray?  Are they NSString instances or some kind of Person class?  If Person class, you need to do something like Person.lastName.

Comment: It is a Person class that has 2 attributes firstName and lastName.

Comment: So  you need to do this:     NSString *cellValue = ((Person *)[personArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]).lastName; // or combine first and last into a nice name string using NSString stringWithFormat

Comment: Worked like a charm! Is there a specific place(book, website, tutorial....) you learned about CoreData? I clearly need to learn more about this subject.

Comment: Apple's documentation is excellent.  Go to developer.apple.com and search for "core data" - that should keep you busy for a while :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you fetch is working, then I would guess that you haven't set the datasource and/or delegate for the tableview.